# ListView inside ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a ListView which holds many views of data in each item. (each item holds different data). 
one of the views of that said ListView is another ListView (in other words - ListView in a ListView).
 When running the code, my main list is shown with all the views including the ListView (With its content - adapter data; at least what you can see without touching since there's lots of data in the inner ListView). The problem is, you get to see the content of the inner ListView but its content is whiter than displayed in the XML as if it's not in focus, moreover the inner ListView isn't scrollable such as when I try to scroll it scrolls the main ListView.
I've been searching around for a lead on my problem but I couldn't see anything related only : "ListView in a ListView isn't recommended" without explanation or "use ExpandableList" but ExpandableList will not serve my needs or meet my design.
I'm afraid I must have that ListView, and not for example a List dialog.

Running Android in Eclipse in Windows 7.

How can I make the inner ListView data as it should be -> according to the XML
and how can I make the inner ListView scrollable?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are about one million apps on the Play Store. Please feel free to name any that use a `ListView` in a `ListView`.

Comment: Do you believe the option does not exist?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it can work, and I would be even more surprised if the resulting UX was sensible.

Comment: Can I know your reasons behind this highly unusual UI setup?

Comment: The reason is that I got a custom endless ListView (Like Facebook's) and every unique item, has got a ListView to its own needs. the endless ListView contains more views than just the ListView, and my inner ListView has got more data than you can see without touching therefore LinearLayout is off the table.

Comment: Design a table layout, look into it and check out my answer bro

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking something similar to the TableLayout of iOS does (scrollable items inside scrollable items) and ExpandableListView ins't a solution for you. Then you need to create your own ViewGroup class that does that.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this in your xml file

```
     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:fadingEdge="none"
         android:overScrollMode="never" >

         <TableLayout
             android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp" >
         </TableLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

you can add  to your table layout programmatically

```
TableLayout TL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
```

just add views to each row you create (like an imageview for example)

```
LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
rowLayout.add(ImageView1);
```

Comment: you can add a list view inside your table row, which in sense is a listview in a listview, just a little hack because the row really isnt a list view but it will appear as one in a scroll view

Comment: look more in depth on how to use table layouts. This is the only way to achieve this and its not very hard either.

Comment: and you will also have to add the listview programmatically to the table layout.